# Как сохранить изменения в программе после её закрытия в qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Мне нужно после работы в приложении(типа набраного текста в LineEdit, выбраных radioButton'ов) сохранить это все в приложении.Чтобы когда запустить еще раз приложение, это все было также как и после закрытия. Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: Переопределяйте `void closeEvent(QCloseEvent * event)` чтобы отловить закрытие окна виджета и в этом методе сохраните данные. А при открытии окна (например в конструкторе) загружайте данные

Comment: Сохраняйте всё вышеописанное в QSettings, а потом оттуда извлекайте.